# Determine the distribution of $Y$ and the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=y$.

Tags: probability

The density function of the two-dimensional random variable $(X, Y)$ is 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{2y^3} \cdot e^{-\frac{x}{y}} & \text{for } 0<x<\infty,\;  0<y<1, \\[8pt] 0, & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

(a) Determine the distribution of $Y$.

(b) Find the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=y$.

Comment: This is phrased in the language appropriate for use by an instructor assigning something to students ((a) Find this. (b) Find that.)  Instead of passing on to us a question that someone else wrote, can you ask your own questions about it.  In particular, what have you done so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: In regards to part (a), I think I need to integrate the joint density function with respect to x. For part (b), I'm assuming I need to compute $f_{Y|X=x}=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X,Y}(x,z)}$. But with both, I struggle with knowing what values to integrate on.

Comment: When integrating with respect to $x$, $y$ is a constant, and thus you can find $\int ax^2e^{-bx}\,dx$ via _integration by parts_ or you can use a substitution to relate the value to $\Gamma(3)$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize it was a $\Gamma(3)$ function. I was able to find that Y has a $U(0,1)$ distribution.